# Showing 2 dropdown list while only one coding control

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Hello guys I am having issue with the dropdownlist. I am adding a asp dropdownlist to a modal popup and i ma using bootstrap theam but when modal pop up the dropdown list is shown 2 time. this image will show you how.

[image]

This is the HTML CODE and

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <div class="form-line">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboGender" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>M</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And code from browser

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
  <div class="form-line">
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
      <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"
        data-id="MainContent_cboGender" title="Other">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">Other</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="bs-caret">
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu open">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
          <li data-original-index="0">
            <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
              <span class="text">M</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
            </a></li>
          <li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span
                class="text">F</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
          <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span
                class="text">Other</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><select name="ctl00$MainContent$cboGender" id="MainContent_cboGender" class="" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="F">F</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due to import of bootstrap-select.js. After removing js import extra button group was removed.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is done using Bootstrap but the other one is probably done through,

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$cboGender" id="MainContent_cboGender" class="" tabindex="-98">
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="F">F</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
```

Comment: the section you are showing is my actual dropdownlist which is declared in the html. But this Div <div class="dropdown-menu open"> is generating on its own and I am unable to find where it is generating from.